# asp.net MVC 2 view with slow UI responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My web application MVC View displays a grid of records, some of which the user can select and post their data back to the server. As long as the record count is in the order of multiples of dozens, the page is responsive. Problems occur when the records are in the order of a thousand and a half.

I've experienced two kinds of problems, one in chrome, one in IE 11. First of all the query to retrieve the records from the DB is kind of slow, but acceptable, let's say that after 5=10 seconds the controller will call a "return view()" passing a model which is a collection of about 1500 records.

Then this happens in Chrome: the browser renders the page quick enough considered the number of record, but after that the page becomes unresponsive in all its elements: as an example, consider the to activate a checkbox, it takes about 10 seconds before you see the check mark after you clicked.

In IE11 this happens instead: the page hangs for about three minutes between the jquery method "document.ready" and its anonymous handler function. After that the page renders all its elements and its responsiveness is acceptable.

My Application is developed in MVC2, and besides jquery, it uses datatables to display the grid, together with bootstrap for styling. Every record has about 20 fields so the page will have 20 form controls (input type=hidden) to post back for each selected record.

Considering that nothing of the above happens when I'm retrieving a few records, can you help me understand what's going on and how I can give performance to my web page?

Thanks in advance......

Comment: you will never "have to" display thousnads of records at once in a web page

Comment: Have you got event handlers attached to the check boxes? If so temporarily remove them (and how the are attached) and see how that affects performance. If that radically improves performance look at optimizing your java script/jQuery. Echoing @ScottSelby, look at why you are returning so much data. For your average user this is overwhelming.

Comment: Actually I found the cause, it's the tens of thousands of input elements which contains information to post back to the server, so I'll have to remove those inputs and refactor form posting. Thanks for your help.